# max Date does not disable next button in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/AdminPanel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

my date picker:

```
$(".datepickBirthday").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
    },
    onClose: function () {
        $(document).on('focusin.bs.modal');
    },
    defaultDate: '-10Y',
    dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
    yearRange: "-70:-10",
    minDate: new Date('-70Y'),
    maxDate: new Date('-10Y'),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

I want to make user restrict to input from last 10 years. That means who is must be 10 years old. But the problem is that it doesn't disable next or prev button when user reaches max or min  year. I tested this http://jsbin.com/babapikebo/edit?html,output. It works on jsbin but not my localhost. Do i miss jquery ui version? If not then how can i make it?
I just want to restrict user to add member of min 10 years old. max is not necessary.

Comment: Change your jquery sequence and try also add bootstrap-datepicker.js on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".datepickBirthday").datepicker({
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
            },
            onClose: function () {
                $(document).on('focusin.bs.modal');
            },
            defaultDate: '-10Y',
            dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
            yearRange: "-70:-10",
            minDate: '-70Y',
            maxDate: '-10Y',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
```

Comment: Actually minDate: new Date('-70Y'), maxDate: new Date('-10Y'), is also working for me this will take all months of min and max year

Comment: another issue: How to set full year of max date and min date. It now disable from current date of max year. i can't set dec 23 2006 or dec 21 1946. I want to have enable full year of 2006 and 1946. @Bharti Sharma

Comment: comment this two lines  minDate: '-70Y', maxDate: '-10Y',

Comment: This enable next and prev button. That;s why user is able to go 2007 by clicking next! any other way ?@Bharti Sharma

Answer (score 1):

See this, calendar will be set for all months for min year and max year, and prev button will be enabled till january of min year and next button will be enabled till max year december.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {        
       $(".datepickBirthday").datepicker({
          
            defaultDate: '-10Y',
            dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
            yearRange: "-70:-10",
            //minDate: '-70Y',
            //maxDate: '-10Y',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
  });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepickBirthday" name="datepickBirthday">
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But i changed ui version 1.8.24 to 1.12.0. Was it version problem? @Bharti Sharma

Comment: I dont think so but try and check

Comment: I checked. When i use 1.8.24, it doesn't work but on 1.12.0.

Comment: can you change the link with this? https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js Then it will be proved whether it was version problem or not. @Bharti Sharma

Comment: yes code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js this file was the problem